# PHP Passing multiple input option variable values, then extracting them

Tags: php, html, forms

I was following one example given on this site that was explaining the 'explode' method of extracting 2 values from a drop-down list, filled dynamically from a database. When I was just trying to get 1 value, this all worked, but I realized I needed to extract more values from the 1 selection from the drop-down. I am trying the 'pipe-explode' method, as you can see, but it is returning nothing. No error, just nothing, not even the 'echo' in the 'isset' function. Any thoughts?

```
$verbs = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM verblist WHERE person = '1s'"); 

echo'<form method="post">
     <select id="verbList" class="dropdownObj" name="verbList">
     <option>Choose a Verb</option>
     ';

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verbs)){
         echo'<option value="'.$row['mainVerb'].'|'.$row['form'].'">'.$row['mainVerb'].' - form '.$row['form'].'</option>';     
     }

     echo'</select>
          <input type="submit" name="verbSubmit" value="Start Game">
          </form>
     ';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $selectedVerb = $_POST['verbList'];
            $result_explode = explode('|', $selectedVerb);
            echo'Your verb selection: <b>'. $result_explode[0] .'</b> and form: <b>'. $result_explode[1] .'</b><br>';          
        }
```

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` is never set - you named your submit button `verbSubmit`

Comment: `$_POST['submit']`  need to be `$_POST['verbSubmit']`

Comment: nice! thank you.. such a stupid mistake!

Comment: @scott.schaffer  better to deleted question because it's a TYPO MISTAKE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in my $_POST, I was calling the wrong input name. I called on 'submit', when the input name was 'verbSubmit'. Changing the name to match the $_POST call solved my issue.